# javascript closure: protecting inner variable

Tags: javascript

I'm using the revealing module pattern somewhat like this:

```
var SomeClosure = function () {

  var SomeInnerVar = 4;

  function InnerGetTheVar() {
     return SomeInnerVar;
  } 

  function InitClosure() {
       // there's something else happening here that requires me to 
       // wait for document.ready before initializing the closure
       setInterval(IncreaseSomeInnerVar, 10000);
  }

  function IncreaseSomeInnerVar() {
     SomeInnerVar = SomeInnerVar  + 1;
  }

  InitClosure();

  return  {
     GetTheVar: InnerGetTheVar
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

   SomeClosure = SomeClosure();
});
```

Now why is it that if in the console I type this:

```
SomeClosure.GetTheVar = 2;
SomeClosure.GetTheVar; // outputs 2!
```

Why doesn't the closure keep `SomeInnerVar` protected? I don't want the outer scope to be able to change SomeInnerVar like that.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just returning an object literal, use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var out = {};

if ( Object.defineProperty ) {
    Object.defineProperty(out, 'GetTheVar', {
        value: InnerGetTheVar,
        writable: false
    });
} else {
    out.GetTheVar = InnerGetTheVar;
}

return out;
```

Comment: Is this going to be cross-browser compatible?

Comment: This'll work in any modern browser that supports ES5. It won't work in IE8 and below. AFAIK, there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: @frenchie - You can do a conditional check. I updated the answer (though it won't stop any code in IE8 from overwriting it).

Comment: @frenchie - This way, if you test your code in any modern browser, it'll bark at you if you try overwriting it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `SomeInnerVar` is still 'protected', in this sense. However, you are overwriting `SomeClosure`'s `GetTheVar` attribute with the value `2`, which isn't 'protected' in the same sense. In other words, you aren't modifying `SomeInnerVar`, you're modifying `GetTheVar`.

Comment: ah ok, and is there a way to prevent the modification of GetTheVar?

Comment: You can make `GetTheVar` a read-only property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty for a run-down of properties in JavaScript.